# Mis dropdown funcionan como botone

Tags: bootstrap, laravel-5

No se que ha pasado, de un día para otro mis dropdown empezaron a funcionar como si fueran un botón.

En mi proyecto siempre funcionaban bien y me puse a seguir con lo que estaba haciendo y me di cuenta que ahora cuando le doy a un dropdown no se despliega si no que actualiza al `href`.

Aquí les dejo mi codigo

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/admin">Admin Blog</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Usuarios <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/admin/usuario/">Listar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/admin/usuario/create">Crear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Categorias <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/admin/categorias/">Listar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/admin/categorias/create">Crear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Articulos <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/admin/articulos">Listar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/admin/articulos/create">Crear</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{!!Auth::user()->name!!} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/logout">Salir</a></li>                
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrese de que esta llamando al archivo `js` de Boostrap de la siguiente forma , además añadiendo el `dropdown()` a su clase `dropdown-toggle` como lo especifica en la documentación de bootstrap [dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

```
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
</script>
```

Comment: Como te dije, amigo. Ayer el codigo me funcionaba y hoy de la nada me me dejo de funcionar. cambie a estos valores en las llamadas del script y si funciono.